# Make submenu in Sidenav menu(ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have side menu

Here is code of it

```
 <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Home</a>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Calendar")">Calendar</a>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "PatientDatabase")">Patient Database</a>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Findings")">Findings</a>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Controlling")">Controlling</a>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Invoices")">Invoices</a>
</div>
```

And JS that's work with it

```
    <script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}
</script>
```

One of my menu point will have submenu.

So when I click for example `Findings` I need to see submenu that raleted to `Findings` .

How I can realize this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two quick solutions:

**1. JavaScript**

instead of `<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Findings")">Findings</a>`

have the markup like

```
<a class="submenu" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Findings")">
  <p>Findings</p>
  <a class="submenu-item" href="#">Sub menu item</a>
  <a class="submenu-item" href="#">Sub menu item</a>
</a>
```

with a stylesheet like

```
.submenu > .submenu-item { display: none }
.submenu.open > .submenu-item { display: block }
```

and your JavaScript like

```
document.querySelectorAll('.submenu').forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    item.classList.toggle('open')
  })
})
```

That's a simple JavaScript toggle for hiding and showing items. The reason I kept the anchor tag on the top level item is so that it still works if JS doesn't.

**2. Detail tag**

HTML has a native tag that shows and hides item

```
<detail>
  <summary>Findings</summary>
  <a href="#">Sub menu item</a>
  <a href="#">Sub menu item</a>
</detail>
```

However, [browser support is not at 100%](http://caniuse.com/#feat=details).